# Reverse Engineering from a DB using EF Power Tools

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-power-tools

I'm using EF Power Tools to Reverse Engineering from a DB.

while in the context it properly writes

```
//TABLE NAME: USERS    
public DbSet<Users> Users { get; set; }
```

in the entity class it writes

```
public partial class User
```

Where the system is changing the name of the table from 'Users' (correct) to 'User' (not correct)?

Please note that i modified the **Context.tt**

```
<#
    foreach (var set in efHost.EntityContainer.BaseEntitySets.OfType<EntitySet>())
    {
#>
        public DbSet<<#= set.Name #>> <#= set.Name #> { get; set; }
<#
    }
#>
```

because in my context i want to have

```
 public DbSet<TABLE_NAME> TABLE_NAME { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be after the line (or not far)

```
namespace <#= code.EscapeNamespace(efHost.Namespace) #>
{
```

in `Entity.tt`

You should find a line `public class <#= efHost.EntityType.Name #>` which you'll have to change.

By the way, I think it's a bad idea, as this way of naming is a kind of convention for EF :

`DbSet` is pluralized, `class` is in the singular.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
set.ElementType.Name
```

to get de Entity name in singular in the Context.tt file.